# Where does the football teams play home matches during the Rugby World Cup?

Tags: football, venues, rugby

Where does football teams play their home matches when the stadiums are involved in [Rugby World Cup 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Rugby_World_Cup) matches?

Apart from Twichenam it seems that other stadiums are used for Premier League's football matches, so how is it possible to play together those sports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don Biglia's comment is pretty much spot on - the soccer team just plays somewhere else, or not at all, when the stadium is in use for the Rugby World Cup. To take a couple of examples:

- Villa Park was used for rugby matches on the 26th and 27th September. Aston Villa played away at Liverpool on the 26th September.
- City of Manchester Stadium will be used for a rugby match on 10th October. Manchester City don't play at all that weekend.

Almost every major soccer ground is a multi-use venue one way or another, so this isn't a new problem for the teams - for example, Old Trafford is hosting the Super League (rugby league) Grand Final on 10th October, which is not really any different from hosting a union match.

Comment: The premier league grounds are available as it's an international weekend and there are no premier league fixtures 10/10

Answer (score 0):

Hi Having just spent 10 days volunteering at Milton Keynes stadium rugby world Cup has an exclusive use agreement with the stadia for a period.   MK dons played Derby at home on the 26th September the next home game should have been this weekend giving us plenty of time to setup for the matches and return to football.   This has been done at all stadia used.